# How to decode passed (nested) Array from didSelectRowAt to another TabBar

Tags: json, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I'm stuck at figuring out how to pass an entire JSON decoded Array(I'm not sure if it's called an array?) from one TabBar to another.

I finally managed to figure out how to pass the selectedRow data to another tab using this YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GL8-eM93EvQ but I am only successful in passing some items instead of the entire decoded JSON.

my current JSON looks like this and I have the JSON as a decoable and have done the unkeyedContainer for the intervals (The values inside the interval are time(x) and value(y):)

```
    [
  {
    "id":1,
    "title":"AirBender",
    "durationMinutes": 25,
    "intervals:":[
      [0.00,  50],
      [10.00,  55],
      [10.00,  73]
    ]
  }
]
```

In the table view TabBar, the didSelectRowAt contains:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let tabbar = tabBarController as! BaseTBController
    tabbar.workoutTitle = jsonErgWorkouts[indexPath.row].title <- This works great
//    tabbar.workoutIntervals = jsonErgWorkouts[indexPath.row] <- This doesn't work
  }
```

This is what I have in the (main) TabBarController Class

```
import UIKit

class BaseTBController: UITabBarController {

  var workoutTitle: String = "Select a Workout"
  // var workoutIntervals: [workoutList] = [] <- I don't know what to declare here
  
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("BaseTBController title:\(workoutTitle)")
    }
}
```

I even tried to declare it as part of the Decodable struct

```
    struct workoutList: Decodable {
      let id: Int
      let title: String
      let durationMinutes: Double
      let intervals: [workoutIntervals]
    }

struct workoutIntervals: Decodable {
  let t: Double // time in min
  let w: Int    // %FTP
  
  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    var arrayContainer = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
    t = try arrayContainer.decode(Double.self)
    w = try arrayContainer.decode(Int.self)
  }
}
```

edit: I just tried to put the workoutIntervals as ANY]

```
var workoutIntervals = [Any]()
```

and it worked to send the workoutIntervals to the other tab. However, now I don't know how I can access the data inside as it's not tied to the decodable struct.

printing out the values via:

```
    for (intervalIndex, workoutIntervals) in tabbar.workoutIntervals.enumerated() {
  print("intIndex:\(intervalIndex) time:\(workoutIntervals)")
```

The result is:

```
intIndex:0 time:workoutIntervals(t: 0.0, w: 50)
intIndex:1 time:workoutIntervals(t: 10.0, w: 55)
intIndex:2 time:workoutIntervals(t: 10.0, w: 73)
```

but like I said, I don't know how to get to the t: and w: since it's not tied to the struct.

Thanks!!

Comment: What is the architecture of your application? are you using MVC or MVVM? Do you have a model class somewhere so you can share data between these tabs instead of passing them all along?

Comment: @Shahin it would be MVC, the class BaseTBController is where I define the variables which hold the data to be passed to each of the tabs. It is working for the items which is not as array of arrays within the JSON. (eg: id / title / duration)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the information. So the `BaseTBController` acts like the **model** part for the application. is that right? So it would be the singleton model that tabs can **request** information from or listen for changes.
In my opinion, To notify the other view controller in another tab about the selected item, You may use `delegate`, `notifications` or `PublishSubject` if you are using **Combine** or **RxSwift**.

Then doesn't matter how the data structure is, you can pass whatever you need to any of those tabs. (like the struct itself or the array within). Is this clear enough?

Comment: I don't use combine nor RxSwift and despite all the things which I have read and tried, this is the only one which works (for me)